# Are there three rational numbers $(a,b,c)$ such that $r(a)+r(b)=r(c)$ where $r(q) = \frac{2q(1-q^2)}{(1+q^2)^2}$?

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, elliptic-curves, rational-numbers

For a given rational number $0<q<1$ let $r(q)$ be
$$
r(q) = \frac{2q(1-q^2)}{(1+q^2)^2}, \quad q \in (0, 1)
$$
Is there a triple $(a, b, c)$ of rational numbers such that
$$
r(a)+r(b)=r(c), \quad a,b,c \in (0,1)?
$$

(**Edit 1:** This question arose when I was playing with magic squares of squares, which, to my knowledge, is an unsolved problem. I am not very familiar with elliptic curves and such, that's why I tried to brute force search a solution and didn't find any after trying about a $1000$ rationals ($10^9$ triples). Some insight on the problem could be very helpful.)

**Edit 2:** As @ThomasAndrews correctly mentioned in the comments, the range of $r$ is in fact the set of values $uv$ such that $u^2+v^2=1$.
The problem above actually follows from the system
$$ \begin{cases}
s_1^2+r_1^2=1,\\
s_2^2+r_2^2=1,\\
s_3^2+r_3^2=1,\\
s_3r_3=s_1r_1+s_2r_2.\\
\end{cases}
$$
I found that [all rational points on the unit circle can be parameterized](https://nilesjohnson.net/teaching/SP19/2137/notes/rationalPointsOnTheCircle.pdf) as
$$
s = \frac{2q}{1+q^2}, \quad r = \frac{1-q^2}{1+q^2}, \quad q \in \mathbb{Q},
$$
hence the last equation is the real problem in the system.

**Edit 3:** The fact that the set $r([0,1])$ is dense in the interval $\left(0, \frac{1}{2}\right)$ ([since $r$ is a continious function](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1719998/1198157)) also might help.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: What's the motivation for this question?

Comment: @Derivative I have edited the post to better express it, but basically it is related to the possible differences between squares in a magic square of squares (if there exists one)

Comment: @AnotherUser thanks a lot!

Comment: The range of $r$ is the set of values $uv,$ where $u,v$ are positive rationals and $u^2+v^2=1.$ Not sure how that helps.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews that is actually kind of where the problem is coming from :) But great observation and thanks a lot! It could be really helpful in case I'm juat overcomplicating things

Comment: Well, give us everything you know. Don't make us guess.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews sorry if the first version of the comment sounded a little bit rude, I misclicked and sent the unfinished comment. Thanks a lot again, I'll add more context.